# Proper way to dispose external resources with hooks in Airflow DAG

Tags: airflow

Proper way to dispose external resources in Airflow DAG

I develop airflow DAGs, and I figure out how to properly dispose of resources like database connections. I use hooks for communication with external systems, and it is unclear to me I should put the hook in this initialization.
Here are my thoughts since I was unable to locate any particular suggestions.

I use LocalExecutor, which runs task operation execution in workers. Workers are created by the forking (os.fork) scheduler process. Workers use LocalTaskJob, which interacts with DagBag and launches a callable for PythonOperator (for example). DagBag reloads frequently (every 30 seconds by default).

It seems that if I create hooks as module variables, they will be reloaded every 30 seconds and there is no chance to perform correct connection disposal.

Another option, if hooks is created inside operator, it can be properly disposed.  Am I correct?